# PHP preg_match_all to get images with ?w= in last

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get image using preg_match_all but cant get it right here is my code. my problem i that i have soome images with .img ext and some with .jpg?w=655&h=357, i dont need .img but need all other valid images it can have ?w=655&h=357 in last or just .jpg or .png

```
$post ='
<img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/180265248066/u/49/f/648326/c/35070/s/34410e29/a2t.img" border="0"/></br>
    <img width="1" height="1" src="http://9to5mac.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/screen-shot-2013-11-29-at-5-17-15-pm.png?w=655&#038;h=357" border="0"/></br>
    <img src="http://images.macrumors.com/article-new/2013/11/mlb.png" alt="MLB" title="mlb.png" width="175" height="175" class="alignright"/></br>
 ';

function catch_that_image($post) {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all("<img.+?src=[\"']([^\"]*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png).*)[\"'].+?>", $post, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  return $first_img;

}
echo catch_that_image($post);
```

Output is

```
http://images.macrumors.com/article-new/2013/11/mlb.png" alt="MLB" title="mlb.png" width="175" height="175" class="alignright
```

I just need url till .png

Thanks

Comment: Use a DOM parser. Using regex to parse HTML is clumsy, hard to maintain and generally awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for parsing HTML. Use a DOM Parser instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    $src =  $image->getAttribute('src');
    $extension = pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($extension !== 'img') {
        echo $src . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[**Online demo.**](https://eval.in/74696)

Comment: thx , but as i have mention it can be any ting after .gif|jpg|jpeg|png or .gif?w=** but i dont want .img ... i think in thin case it will take .img also